# Failed Email Delivery for some multi-lingual emails with MailKit while it works like a charm with legacy System.Net.Mail

Tags: c#, smtpclient, mailkit

We are using MailKit to send notification emails which can be in multi languages.

For languages like French, Japanese, and Spanish we are not able to deliver the emails. However, there is no failure in the SendAsync method in MailKit.

1- I noticed for French that it had to do with the accents in the email body. If the sentence happens to have no accents, the mail goes through to recipients. Otherwise, a failed delivery message with no explaination.

2- English and German text emails seem to work fine, except that they show in Junk email.

3- The messages are released to SMTP server and rejected there and returned to sender with mail delivery failed. No extra useful information.

A legacy system owned that also delivers email notifications does not have that problem, and by looking at their code, they are using the legacy System.Net.Mail not MailKit. That was the only difference. So I replaced our usage of MailKit with the legacy System.Net.Mail which we probably should not use based on message on the doc indicating that it is becoming obsolete, and it worked. The messages in all supported languages are being sent and they arrive in Inbox (not junk folder).  No mail delivery failures whatsoever.

So I suspected that the way we construct the message might be problematic in MailKit.

In MailKit we used BodyBuilder to set the text as follows

```
     private BodyBuilder FormatTextEncoding(EmailBodyType emailBodyType, string messageBody)
        {            
            BodyBuilder builder = new BodyBuilder();            
            switch (emailBodyType)
            {
                case EmailBodyType.HTML:
                    builder.HtmlBody = messageBody;                    
                    break;

                case EmailBodyType.TEXT:
                    builder.TextBody = messageBody;
                    break;

                default:
                    _logger.LogWarning("new content type:{contentType}", emailBodyType);
                    builder.TextBody = messageBody;
                    break;
            }     
            
            return builder;
        }
```

The caller of this helper sets the body as follows

```
 // set the message body
 emailMessage.Body = bodyBuilder.ToMessageBody();
```

Within the GenerateEmailMessage function.

```
/// <summary>
        /// Transforms consume result message to MimeMessage to be accepted by SMTP client
        /// as ready message for sending.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="consumeResult"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public EmailNotificationMessage GenerateEmailMessage(ConsumeResult<string, SendEmail> consumeResult)
        {
            // retrieve Kafka topic message
            var msg = consumeResult.Message.Value;            
            
            // new email message to return
            var emailMessage = new MimeMessage();                  

            if(msg == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("[GenerateEmailMessage] Code bug. Message in Kafka topic cannot be null.");
            }
            
            // reference the email body
            var emailBody = msg.detail.emailBody;

            // based on content type, set Html body or Text body
            // for bad content type, treat as text
            // and create bodyBuilder
            var bodyBuilder = FormatTextEncoding(emailBody.contentType, emailBody.messageBody);                        

            // set the subject            
            emailMessage.Subject = msg.detail.subject;
            // set the message body
            emailMessage.Body = bodyBuilder.ToMessageBody();

            // set the from list
            foreach (var fromAddress in msg.detail.from)
            {
                emailMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(fromAddress.displayName, fromAddress.emailAddress));
            }

            // check if sender is set and set the Sender value for MimeMessage
            if (msg.detail.sender != null)
            {
                emailMessage.Sender = new MailboxAddress(msg.detail.sender.displayName, msg.detail.sender.emailAddress);
            }

            // set the recipients
            foreach (var toAddress in msg.detail.to)
            {
                emailMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(toAddress.displayName, toAddress.emailAddress));
            }

            // set replyTo field if different than from field
            if (msg.detail.replyTo != null)
            {
                foreach (var replyToAddress in msg.detail.replyTo)
                {
                    emailMessage.ReplyTo.Add(new MailboxAddress(replyToAddress.displayName, replyToAddress.emailAddress));
                }               
            }     
            
            // set CC and BCC
            if (msg.detail.cc != null)
            {
                foreach (var ccAddress in msg.detail.cc)
                {
                    emailMessage.Cc.Add(new MailboxAddress(ccAddress.displayName, ccAddress.emailAddress));
                }
            }

            if (msg.detail.bcc != null)
            {
                foreach (var bccAddress in msg.detail.bcc)
                {
                    emailMessage.Bcc.Add(new MailboxAddress(bccAddress.displayName, bccAddress.emailAddress));
                }
            }

            // set message importance
            switch(msg.detail.messageImportance )
            {
                case MessageImportance.HIGH:
                    emailMessage.Importance = MimeKit.MessageImportance.High;
                    break;
                case MessageImportance.LOW:
                    emailMessage.Importance = MimeKit.MessageImportance.Low;
                    break;
                case MessageImportance.NORMAL:
                    emailMessage.Importance = MimeKit.MessageImportance.Normal;
                    break;
                default:
                    _logger.LogWarning("unknown message importance: {importance}. Will not be set.", msg.detail.messageImportance);
                    break;
            }

            // set message priority
            switch (msg.detail.messagePriority)
            {
                case MessagePriority.URGENT:
                    emailMessage.Priority = MimeKit.MessagePriority.Urgent;
                    break;
                case MessagePriority.NORMAL:
                    emailMessage.Priority = MimeKit.MessagePriority.Normal;
                    break;
                case MessagePriority.NON_URGENT:
                    emailMessage.Priority = MimeKit.MessagePriority.NonUrgent;
                    break;
                default:
                    _logger.LogWarning("unknown message priority: {priority}. Will not be set.", msg.detail.messagePriority);
                    break;
            }

            // set X-message priority
            switch (msg.detail.xMessagePriority)
            {
                case XMessagePriority.HIGH:
                    emailMessage.XPriority = MimeKit.XMessagePriority.High;
                    break;
                case XMessagePriority.HIGHEST:
                    emailMessage.XPriority = MimeKit.XMessagePriority.Highest;
                    break;
                case XMessagePriority.LOW:
                    emailMessage.XPriority = MimeKit.XMessagePriority.Low;
                    break;
                case XMessagePriority.LOWEST:
                    emailMessage.XPriority = MimeKit.XMessagePriority.Lowest;
                    break;
                case XMessagePriority.NORMAL:
                    emailMessage.XPriority = MimeKit.XMessagePriority.Normal;
                    break;
                default:
                    _logger.LogWarning("unknown message priority: {priority}. Will not be set.", msg.detail.xMessagePriority);
                    break;
            }

            EmailNotificationMessage message;
            var messageId = msg.identifier.eventId;

            var instanceId = EmailNotificationMessage.DEFAULT_CUSTOMER_INSTANCE_ID;
            if (msg.meta.instanceId.HasValue)
            {
                instanceId = msg.meta.instanceId.Value;
            }           
            
            if (msg.identifier.eventId == null)
            {
                // generate globally unique message ID
                messageId = MimeKit.Utils.MimeUtils.GenerateMessageId();
                message = new EmailNotificationMessage(emailMessage,
                                                       messageId, msg.identifier.eventType, instanceId);   
            }
            else
            {
                // pass through the message ID           
                message = new EmailNotificationMessage(emailMessage,
                                                       messageId, msg.identifier.eventType, instanceId);   
            }

            return message;
        }



/// <summary>
        /// Handles the consume result message.
        /// Calls GetEmailMessage to transform to message acceptable by SMTP client
        /// Calls SendEmailAsync
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="consumeResult"></param>
        /// <param name="cancellationToken"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task HandleMessageAsync(ConsumeResult<string, SendEmail> consumeResult, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // cancel upon cancellation request
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            
            // convert Kafka message to Email message format for SMTP service 
            var emailMessage = GenerateEmailMessage(consumeResult);                

            // send the email 
            await SendEmailAsync(emailMessage, cancellationToken);           
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Uses the SMTP client prototype or interface to SendMessageAsync
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="message"></param>
        /// <param name="cancellationToken"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task SendEmailAsync(EmailNotificationMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            await _smtpClient.SendMessageAsync(_config, message, cancellationToken);
            

            _logger.LogInformation("Sending email with {EmailNotificationMessage}", message.Format());
        }
```

And here is how we send the message finally

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Uses the MailKit SMTP client to send message to SMTP Server.
        /// Generates short-living client for each message
        /// Connects to SMTP server first. Then attempts to Send a message.
        /// Then disconnects from SMTP server to avoid leaking connections.
        /// Then the SMTP client is disposed appropriately
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="config"></param>
        /// <param name="message"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task SendMessageAsync(EmailConfiguration config, EmailNotificationMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            using (var client = _smtpClientFactory() )
            {
                await client.ConnectAsync(config.SMTPServer, config.Port, false, cancellationToken);
                               

                await client.SendAsync(message.Message, cancellationToken);

                await client.DisconnectAsync(true, cancellationToken);
            }
        }
    }
```

We can always just revert to using System.Net.Mail but since it is recommended by Microsoft not to use, it does not seem right. What might be going wrong here? Could it also be a problem with the legacy SMTP IIS server not able to accept these MailKit messages? Or are we constructing the email body wrong?

NOTE: I also tried skipping all that encoding `SetText` logic and directly set the bodyBuilder.HtmlText and Text to the message string. That also didn't work.

Thanks for reading and I appreciate the help in advance.

**EDIT**
This code using System.Net.Mail works just fine. It was quick code as test to check if swapping MailKit can resolve this.

[image]

notice how it retrieved the TextPart and other MimeMessage components to generate MailMessage component for the legacy Smtp Client.

Here is an example failure report for message in French
[image]

**EDIT 2**

Added Protocol Logs for a message that fails to deliver
[image]

**EDIT 3**

For comparison purposes here is an image of the logs for a successful English message:

[image]

Comment: Please provide a full working sample that illustrates the issue. It can probably all fit within 50 lines of code. Your current code is a convoluted mess and you are likely forcing an encoding that doesn't make sense for the text content. (Hint: don't use UTF-32 or UTF-7 for email bodies, neither of those make sense)

Comment: Any mail client that can handle UTF-32 or UTF-7 in email is guaranteed to also support UTF-8, so just use UTF-8. UTF-32 is also a binary encoding which is not supported by most mail transfer software which requires clients to base64 encode it.

Comment: that's what I tried first, to remove the encoding SetText mess and simply use bodyBuilder and set the text (either HTML or Text) but it also failed to work.

Comment: @jstedfast I added most of the code that is involved.  ```HandleMessageAsync``` is the entry point of the message coming in from Kafka consumer.  Then ```GenerateEmailMessage``` is called and then ```SendEmailAsync```.

Comment: Just for your information: RFC 8255 defines a multipart format for multilingual messages.

Comment: i'm trying to send an email with c# and kafka if you have a tutorial or sample code that you know, please share it with me. I need so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core of the problem turned out to be that the messages being sent out were 8-bit (e.g. `Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit`) and even though the Postfix SMTP server support the `8BITMIME` extension, when Postfix went on to relay the message to an IIS SMTP server, the IIS SMTP server did not support the `8BITMIME` extension and so Postfix was unable to deliver the message.

The solution was to call `message.Prepare (EncodingConstraint.SevenBit);` to force MimeKit to calculate the best encoding to use for 8bit MIME part and either quoted-printable or base64 encode them.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This code has been edited after using TextPart directly so I figured maybe I need to use body builder and TextPart.

Comment: as mentioned this is what I tried earlier but also didn't work...hence I tried to go back to incorporating the encoding which is coming in from the caller. That said, I double checked now and tried again... still delivery failure for French messages.

Comment: What exactly is the error message? Have you tried getting a ProtocolLog? `new SmtpClient (new ProtocolLogger ("smtp.log"))`

Comment: The problem is that the "delivery failed" message you are getting is telling you that your SMTP server failed to deliver the message. The problem isn't the SmtpClient. If it was, then the SMTP server would have given you an error during the SendAsync() method call. So the question is: why? The most obvious answer is that the recipient address doesn't exist and so chasing this theory that it has something to do with the text body of the message is 100% guaranteed to be a waste of time. An SMTP server won't fail to deliver a message due to the body of the message.

Comment: I understand that but when I swap the MailKit with the legacy System.Net.Mail it works fine. If I send English and German with MailKit, it works, but the moment I try to send French or Japanese, delivery fails. I understand it leaves the client and reaches SMTP server and fails there but it's concerning that swapping the client fixes it. It is 100% reproducible and the body of the message is the problem.

Comment: are there any headers that MailKit is appending that might be rejected by legacy SMTP server? I am not saying the client is the problem but I wanted to double check. Since working with folks managing the SMTP server didn't bring any results.  It is still concerning that swapping back to System.Net.Mail is the only way now to get it to work.

Comment: Can you write up a VERY simple program with hard-coded text body strings? Can you try sending the message to a test account so that you can post the SMTP protocol logs unredacted? I need something to go on, right now all the info you've shared in your question is vague. I am 100% able to send messages with all kinds of non-ASCII text using MimeKit/MailKit just fine, so I know that MimeKit and MailKit can do this just fine.

Comment: "are there any headers that MailKit is appending that might be rejected by legacy SMTP server?" This is why I am asking for protocol logs :) I don't have super-powers that allow me to read the packets that are being sent by your program to your SMTP server from across the globe :p

Comment: oh lol ok I thought there are some standard headers always added that might be rejected by SMTP server. I will try to get the logs per your above comment and get back to you. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: I added an image of the protocol logs for a French email that fails to send. FYI the first SMTP server is Postfix (Ubuntu) which then relays to IIS server. The latter drops the message or rejects it for some reason.

Question: is there any minimum SMTP server version required to be used with MailKit?

Comment: Try doing `emailMessage.Prepare (EncodingConstraint.SevenBit);` after constructing the message. If it has anything to do with the body, then the only explanation is that IIS doesn't support 8BITMIME.

Comment: funny. I was looking at https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc8255/ RFC 8255 per above suggestion and seeing all examples with 7bit transfer and was curious if it could be that. I tried to Prepare with 7 bit and all the multi-lingual emails started to arrive just fine. Thanks for your help and support!

Comment: Awesome! Glad we managed to work out the problem :-)